# Pipe multiple commands then write to file

Tags: go

I'm trying to pipe multiple `*exec.Cmd` and then write to file. When I try with one cmd and output to file, it writes to the file. However, when I try with multiple commands and output to file, it does not. But the exec.Cmd seems to be piping as it can stdout correctly.

```
outfile, err := os.Create("./out.txt")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer outfile.Close()

c1 := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "while sleep 1; do echo test; done")
c1.Stdout = outfile
_ = c1.Run()

for {

}
```

This above code writes to file every one second.
But when I try this:

```
outfile, err := os.Create("./out.txt")
if err != nil {
    panic(err)
}
defer outfile.Close()

c1 := exec.Command("sh", "-c", "while sleep 1; do echo test; done")
c2 := exec.Command("grep", "t")
c2.Stdin, _ = c1.StdoutPipe()
c2.Stdout = outfile
_ = c2.Start()
_ = c1.Run()
c2.Wait()
```

This does not output anything.

But when I change `c2.Stdout = outfile` to `c2.Stdout = os.Stdout`, then it prints out the output correctly

I can't figure out why this is happening. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Probably `grep` is noticing that it's writing to a regular file and block buffering the output.

Comment: @WilliamPursell Thank you! That led me to the solution below

Answer (score 1):

So, the grep is not noticing that it's writing to a regular file.

By changing this line from:

```
c2 := exec.Command("grep", "t")
```

to this works and writes to the file correctly

```
c2 := exec.Command("grep", "t", "--line-buffered")
```